# Toolbar disappears after adding three subviews

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiimageview, uicollectionview

Hi I am trying to add items from collection view to uiview on the same screen. As  user tap to a cell I find and put it to mycreationview below (and I also want user to move around these added uiimages ) . And I have a toolbar at the top to go back etc. Now when I tap cells 3 times 3 images is added to view but then the toolbar disappears and back button on it hides to top/left with only quarter of it visible, how can I debug this  ?

```
    myCollectionViewCell* cell=(myCollectionViewCell* ) [self.myCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:index];
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:cell.myCellImageView.image];
    iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    NSLayoutConstraint * constraint1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:iv attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.myCreationView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.4f constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint * constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:iv attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.myCreationView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.4f constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint * constraint3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:iv attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.myCreationView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:0 constant:10];
    NSLayoutConstraint * constraint4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:iv attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.myCreationView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:0 constant:10];

    [iv setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    iv.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
    iv.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [self.myCreationView addSubview:iv];
    [self.myCreationView addConstraint:constraint1];
    [self.myCreationView addConstraint:constraint2];
    [self.myCreationView addConstraint:constraint3];
    [self.myCreationView addConstraint:constraint4];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question. I made the view a bit smaller and not to touch toolbar and the problem go away. So I guess there is a constraint created if they touch each other.